# Longpressing EditText causes Crash

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext, contextmenu

For some reason, it is trying to bring up a context menu when I long press an `EditText` box (such as to paste in data).

Here is LogCat:

```
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at com.---.---.Comments.onCreateContextMenu(Comments.java:352)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.view.View.createContextMenu(View.java:7781)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.view.View.createContextMenu(View.java:7789)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.view.View.createContextMenu(View.java:7789)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ContextMenuBuilder.show(ContextMenuBuilder.java:81)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.showContextMenuForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2201)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:612)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:612)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:612)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:612)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:612)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:2969)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:612)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:4154)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:4123)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:7875)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:16945)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-26 12:00:22.243: E/AndroidRuntime(22300):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 12:00:22.250: W/ActivityManager(291):   Force finishing activity com.---.rat---/.Comments
```

The code of my ContextMenu with line causing NullPointer:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    android.view.MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.comments_context, menu);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Available Actions");

    android.view.MenuItem Edit = menu.findItem(R.id.editComment);
    android.view.MenuItem Delete = menu.findItem(R.id.deleteComment);

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    int position = info.position;
    ListView lv = (ListView) v;
    int firstVisible = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View rowView = lv.getChildAt(position - firstVisible);

  // this is the line where there is a null pointer.  (Obviousness in an `EditText` box,  this `TextView` doesn't exist!

    ReviewUser = ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.labelReviewCommentUser)).getText().toString();
    ReviewComment = ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.labelReviewComment)).getText().toString();


    // Other Stuff Edited Out

}
```

The EditText box is created in my `onCreate`:

```
EtComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTweetComment);
```

At the very end of `onCreate` is this:

registerForContextMenu(getListView());

Also, just above where I declare the EditText, I setup listview:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.comment_header, listView, false);

        listView = getListView();
        listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
        listView.setClickable(false);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

The `EditText` Box is in the `ListView` header (`comment_header`).  Not sure if that matters.

Main Question:  **Why is it trying to register a ContextMenu by longpressing an EditText?**

***EDIT/UPDATE***:

I beleive CommonsWare answers this now I am struggling with code for it:

> Please compare v with getListView() to see if they are the same
>   object or not. If they are not, just chain to the superclass.

How do you achieve this?  When I call this, `registerForContextMenu(getListView());` I believe, it will ALWAYS open the `ContextMenu` with the `ListView` in mind based on that code, so how can I do the comparison whether I am long pressing a `ListView` vs an `EditText` box?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What line in the above code is 352?

Comment: The NPE could be due to either (a) The TextView does not exist or (b) The getText() method is returning null.  Why dont you look into this?

Comment: @FoamyGuy  The First line after where I say "// this is the line where there is a null pointer."

Comment: @EJK  Yes, the `TextView` does NOT exisit inside the `EditText` box.  The main question is:  Why is it trying to register a ContextMenu by longpressing an `EditText`?

Comment: It is not "trying to register a `ContextMenu`" for the `EditText` -- it already did. ~99% of Android devices have a system-defined context menu (or action mode on newer devices) for `EditText`. If you are using a `ContextMenu`, examine the `View v` parameter to `onCreateContextMenu()` and only deal with yours, just chaining to the superclass for the rest.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, I see what you are saying.... The `ContextMenu` in my ListView is interfering with the system function.  I only use the View v in my onCreateContext -- `ListView lv = (ListView) view`.  I am not seeing where else it could be interfering?

Comment: `onCreateContextMenu()` is called for *all context menus* within that activity. You are crashing because you are assuming that the context menu is being created for the `ListView`, and that will not always be the case for this activity. Please compare `v` with `getListView()` to see if they are the same object or not. If they are not, **just chain to the superclass**.

Comment: I completely understand what is happeneing, and what needs to be done now, thanks!  This is where I am at: I compared `v` and `getListView()` inside the `onCreateContext` and it always was the same: The `ListView` widget. Then I realized that is probably because I call `getListView()` EACH time the context menu is registered.  So I assume I make the comparison before?  If so, What do I compare `getListView()` with if v hasn't been initialized yet?  Is there a way to get the current view - or am I overthinking this?

Comment: Did you found solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can pop-up a ContextMenu dialog to handle long press on the `EditText` widget. Generally this menu would contain things like:

- Cut
- Copy
- Paste
- Select All
- Select Text

The action taken when longpressing on the EditText is dependent on the device you are running on due to various differences in the platform versions, and OEM ui's that get implemented across the range of devices. So without knowing more about what device you are on I can only give a general idea of why the OS *could* be popping up a context menu.

Comment: Doing lots of research, and ultimately listening to Commonsware, you are correct.  Now I just have to figure out how to implement it...